# Text difficult to copy-paste in some reader only on a specific PDF generated with PDFLatex

Tags: pdftex, characters, copy-paste

So, it's a strange question: I know that LaTeX has some problems with the copy-paste from a PDF which, sometimes, need thing like the package cmap. But at this point I never needed such thing, as my PDF generated with PDFLatex was always crystal clear.

But currently I am working on a thesis (with a *large* number of packages) and, strangely, the texts in the generated PDF are difficult to select.

The point that make my question different from the classic one is that the problem seems to happen only with certain editors (like Sumatra PDF) and not with other editor (like Adobe Reader), for the same PDF, which is very strange: if the problem was a character problem like ligatures and special characters, it should appear for every reader.

What am I missing?

edit :

Some precision and illustration.

The problem : on the phrase (in french sorry):

> "La robotique voit aujourd'hui l'apparition de nouveaux usages, apportant de >nouvelles contraintes et appelant donc à de nouvelles techniques : on >cherche par exemple à pouvoir déployer des robots dans les espaces publics >ou encore dans les foyers."

A copy from adobe give the good result. A copy from sumatra give :

> La r ob ot i q u e v oi t au j ou r d ’ h u i l ’ ap p ar i t i on
>   d e n ou v e au x
>   u s age s , ap p or t an t d e n ou v e l l e s c on t r ai n t e s e t
>   ap p e l an t d on c
>   à d e
>   n ou v e l l e s t e c h n i q u e s : on
>   c h e r c h e
>   p ar e x e m
>   p l e
>   à p ou v oi r d é p l oy e r d e s r ob ot s d an s
>   l e s e s p ac e s p u b l i c s ou
>   e n c or e d an s l e s f oy e r s .

And it give when i do the selection : 
[image: copy].

We see the holes in the selected text.

Ideally i want to make my pdf selectable in every editor. It's not a general problem in sumatra as it suceed to open other pdf, so it dhould be possible to fix i guess.

The packages in my tex (sorry, it's a big document with a lot of package):

```
\pdfobjcompresslevel 0
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,final, DIV=12, listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc, toc=bibliography, open=right, chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[greek,english,french]{babel}
\def\frenchtablename{Tableau}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\g}[1]{\og #1 \fg}

\definecolor{usccardinal}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.4}
\usepackage[final]{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotehyper}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}
\usepackage{etoc, blindtext}

\newlength\tocrulewidth
\setlength{\tocrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\newcommand{\chaptertoc}[1][Chaptertoc]{%
\begingroup
\textbf{Sommaire du chapitre :} 
\parindent=0em
\etocsettocstyle{\rule{\linewidth}{\tocrulewidth}\vskip0.5\baselineskip}{\rule{\linewidth}{\tocrulewidth}}
\localtableofcontents 
\endgroup
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@pnumwidth{2em}
\makeatother

\rmfamily % initialise la famille de font pour les deux commandes suivantes, sinon ce n'est fait qu'au begin document
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{b}{sc}{<->ssub*cmr/bx/sc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub*cmr/bx/sc}{}

\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true, style=authoryear, autopunct=false, uniquename=false, uniquelist=false, mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=2,bibencoding=utf8, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex} % On utilise biblatex à la place de bibtex, ce qui permet une meilleure compatibilité avec koma-script. Pour ne pas s'embeter on lui demande de mimer le comportement de natbib, ce qui permet d'avoir la commande citep.
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib} % on précise la source biblio

\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{ \usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcitetext}[\mkbibfootnotetext]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{textcite}}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}%
   \multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\longcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \defcounter{maxnames}{99}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

  \DeclareCiteCommand*{\longcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \defcounter{maxnames}{99}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\longparencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \defcounter{maxnames}{99}%
    \DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}%
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\longparencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \defcounter{maxnames}{99}%
    \DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}%
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}  

\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterskip=5\baselineskip]{chapter}
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\Large\mdseries}
%
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot%
  \IfUsePrefixLine{%
    \par\nobreak\vspace{-\parskip}\vspace{-.2\baselineskip}%
    \rule{0.9\textwidth}{.5pt}%trace une ligne
  }{\enskip}%
}


\renewcommand{\chapterlineswithprefixformat}[3]{%
  \ifstr{#2}{}{#2#3\par\bigskip\hrule}{#2#3}%
  %
}

\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
  \thesection\enskip
  \textcolor{RoyalBlue!50}{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{2pt}{\baselineskip}}\enskip
}

\addtokomafont{section}{\clearpage\phantomsection}

\usepackage[automark, headsepline, footsepline,plainfootsepline, plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles

\ihead[]{}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark} 
\ifoot[Nils Beaussé]{Nils Beaussé} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[format=plain, font=small, labelfont=bf, textfont=it]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\definecolor{bleu_defaut}{RGB}{31, 119, 180}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}%
\makeatletter
\let\oldabs\abs
\def\abs{\@ifstar{\oldabs}{\oldabs*}}
%
\let\oldnorm\norm
\def\norm{\@ifstar{\oldnorm}{\oldnorm*}}
\makeatother

\DeclareMathOperator{\e}{e}
\usepackage[french,onelanguage,noend]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox,xintexpr}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\newcommand{\norme}[1]{\left\Vert #1\right\Vert}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\addsubsec{\secdef\@addsubsec\@saddsubsec}
\newcommand*{\@addsubsec}{}
\def\@addsubsec[#1]#2{\subsection*{#2}\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}
  \if@twoside\ifx\@mkboth\markboth\markright{#1}\fi\fi
}
\newcommand*{\@saddsubsec}[1]{\subsection*{#1}\@mkboth{}{}}
\makeatother

\definecolor{bleuNuit}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.6}
\definecolor{rougepr}{rgb}{0.6, 0.0, 0.0}

\date{\today}

\sloppy

\newcommand*{\tg}[1]{\textgreek{#1}}

\newcommand{\sebrace}[1]{%
    \ifcase#1\or\or%
        \newcommand\NumOfStruts{\mathstrut\\}%
    \or 
        \newcommand\NumOfStruts{\mathstrut\\\mathstrut\\}%
    \or
        \newcommand\NumOfStruts{\mathstrut\\\mathstrut\\\mathstrut\\}%
    \or
        \newcommand\NumOfStruts{\mathstrut\\\mathstrut\\\mathstrut\\\mathstrut\\}%
    \or
        \newcommand\NumOfStruts{\mathstrut\\\mathstrut\\\mathstrut\\\mathstrut\\\mathstrut\\}%
    \fi
    \raisebox{\xinttheiexpr [1](0.5*((#1)-1))\relax\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{%
        $\left\{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} \NumOfStruts\mathstrut\end{array}\right.$
    }
}

\newcommand{\sebracein}[1]{%
    \ifcase#1\or\or%
        \newcommand\NumOfStruts{\mathstrut\\}%
    \or 
        \newcommand\NumOfStruts{\mathstrut\\\mathstrut\\}%
    \or
        \newcommand\NumOfStruts{\mathstrut\\\mathstrut\\\mathstrut\\}%
    \fi
    \raisebox{\xinttheiexpr [1](0.5*((#1)-1))\relax\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{%
        \left\{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} \NumOfStruts\mathstrut\end{array}\right.
    }
}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table des matières}

\usepackage[float=false]{scrhack}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  locale=FR,
  detect-all,
  output-decimal-marker={,},
  group-minimum-digits = 3,
  group-separator={\,},
  number-unit-product={\,},
  group-digits = integer,
  inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{\cdot}}
}
```

**EDIT : NEW MINIMAL EXAMPLE :**

```
%%%%%%%%%%% LOT OF PACKAGES AND DEFINITIONS %%%%%%%%%%
\pdfobjcompresslevel 0

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,final, DIV=12, listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc, toc=bibliography, open=right, chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage[greek,english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[final]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%%%%%%%%%%% LOT OF PACKAGES AND DEFINITIONS END %%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%% BEGENNING OF THE WORK ON FOOTNOTES %%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%% some package %%%%%%%
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

%%%%%% begin %%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
%%%%%% TEST %%%%%%

\chapter{TEST}
\section{Introduction}

EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE

EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE


\end{document}
```

Give :

> E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E
>   E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E
>   E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E
>   E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E

if selected on certain viewer like the last version of sumatra.

Note that this seem to not be a problem of accentuation as

> ÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉ
>   EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
>
> EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
>   EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE

Give :

> É É É É É É É É É É É É É É É É
>   E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E
>   E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E
>   E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E

Comment: no pdfviewer can be different. I just had an example where sumatra copied a mathematical c and the adobe reader a mathematical b (which was correct). But without more data about the fonts and the chars involved it is not possible to say more.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I think you meant "No. Pdfviewers _can_ be different".

Comment: Hum Ok, the font is a classical latin modern T1, nothing exotic here ...

Comment: Ok, @UlrikeFischer  : I have precised my problem with some illustration, image and with the begenning of the document ;)

Comment: Make a small but *complete* example. It should be easy to use only one of the offending paragraphs as body and to remove unnecessy stuff from the preamble.

Comment: OK @UlrikeFischer, i will do that ;)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It's done, i have added a small and complete example at the bottom of the post ;)

Comment: I have no problems with your example and sumatra 3.1.2. You could put the pdf somewhere for download, then I could try this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have made few more test : thje problem appears only with sumatra pdf 3.2 and NOT with 3.1.2, may be a bug in sumatra ? I figured it because i used sumatra for a long time and had no problem until an upgrade few days ago.
I have raised an issue of the github of sumatra and on their website :
https://forum.sumatrapdfreader.org/t/copy-paste-fails-in-sumatra-pdf-3-2-and-note-in-3-1-2-on-certain-pdf/2768/2
https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf/issues/1505

The document, for test with 3.2 : 
https://mega.nz/#!aPoXjQDT!2t3-D6fAYUGeGYI2SohytTQemd69JAhApWgkZnzJ6-o

Comment: Hm. I can try later. But the other bug in sumatra is that the "look for updates" menu lies - it claimed for me that I have the newest version ;-).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, but it's clearly a lie :p
Feel free to upvote the github report if you notice the same bug ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally, to resume the discussions in the comments and on other site : It appears that this is not a latex problem. But a SumatraPDF bug that seems to have been introduced between the 3.1.2 and the 3.2.

I have opened an issue on the github of sumatra_pdf and the bug have been reproduced and it is currently tracked by the collaborator of the soft.

Feel free to participate on the github page of the bug : 
https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf/issues/1505